# What is "EOS" short for?

Tags: naming

I can't seem to find what the acronym EOS means. I did search, but other than a sort-of consensus that the E is for Ethereum, I did not find anything else. Only conjecture.

So, is there a word-of-God?

Comment: I like the "Expandable Operating System" because this is what EOS was designed for

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It formally doesn't stand for anything at all!

People have come up with all sorts of backronyms - "Ethereum On Steroids", "Enterprise Operating System", "Evolution Of Scalability", for example.

source: [eos.io FAQ](https://eos.io/faq)

> What does EOS stand for?
>
> We believe that EOS means different things to different people. We
>   have received numerous amazing interpretations of what EOS stands for
>   or what it should stand for so we have decided not to formally define
>   it ourselves.

Comment: This came up when I was an employee at Block.one and Dan Larimer said in my hearing that he didn't want the company to define it.

Answer (score 2):

Officially it does not stand for anything.  During an interview with Ivan on Tech Dan Larimer stated that despite the speculation that EOS stands for "Ethereum on Steroids" it actually does not mean anything.

It is very possible that EOS means something to the inner circle of people involved in the project but to the public it officially has no meaning.

Comment: Here's the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7HQlcl-LlQ&feature=youtu.be&t=1h27m53s

Answer (score -4):

EOS = Enterprise Operating System